# What is the difference between these two regular expression statements

Tags: regex

`([1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9])` and `(1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9)`

I would like to check each port of a Cisco Switch for a specified set of commands.  The ports are numbered 1 thru 9.  Using a regular expression I want the code to choose each one of the numbers to validate the configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one will match any of:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 |
```

while the second one will match any of:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Note that the first one is equivalent to: `([123456789|])`.

Of course, the regex that would do the job for your problem is (slightly) different: `([123456789])`, or `([1-9])`.

Comment: What if I just wanted to search for the following 

(1|2|3|6|7|8)

Comment: Then you can use: `[123678]`.

Comment: Will it look at each number individually or any of the numbers listed

Comment: @Pirates It treats brackets as a set. It will choose **only one** of the elements within the brackets.

Comment: @Pirates this will match only *one* number chosen from the set.

Comment: How do I choose more then one number in a set?

Comment: @Pirates: simply use `[123678]+` to choose one or more elements; `[123678]{n}` to chose exactly *n* elements, or `[123678]{n,m}` to choose from *n* to *m* elements.

Comment: ok,   

[1|2|3|4|7|8|9|0]{2}  only matches 11,12,13,14,17,18,19 sets 
but is it checking each of the matches or the first available match

Comment: No, it would match any combination of two character that’s in the brackets (11, 1|, 12, ... 42, ... ||, ...). Please care to edit your question to specify your needs, you would get more satisfying answers.

Comment: interface GigabitEthernet0\/([1|2|3|5|6|8|9]).*\n(.*\n)*.* description Unused Port  -----  I need to search each port on the cisco switch for this description. I am having an issue with verifying each port.

Comment: I’ll be a bit more specific: as it is now, your question has been answered. If you realize you didn’t get what you wanted, **edit your question adding: an example of what you want to match and the regex you already wrote**. Also, please read the answers and drop that pipe (`|`) in your sets. Cheers!

Answer (score 6):

The first regular expression doesn't really make sense: it means "choose 1 or choose | or choose 2 or choose 3 or ... or choose 9"

The second means "choose 1 or choose 2 or choose 3 or ... or choose 9"

I think the regular expression you were looking for in the first regular expression is `([123456789])`, which is exactly equivalent to the second regular expression.

To make it even simpler, you can use `([1-9])`, which just indicates a range.

For more information about regular expressions, more specifically perl compatible regular expressions (PCREs), you can look [here](https://qualysguard.qualys.com/qwebhelp/fo_portal/module_pc/policies/regular_expression_symbols.htm).

Answer (score 1):

The first one will match any character in the set

> |123456789

The second one will match

> 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 or 6 or 7 or 8 or 9

.

Comment: Ok, how about 1 & 2 & 3 & 6 & 8?

Comment: maybe something like this 

([1]|[2]|[3]|[6]|[8])

Comment: what is the string you are trying to match? Can you write that string out for us?

Comment: interface GigabitEthernet0\/([1|2|3|5|6|8|9]).*\n(.*\n)*.* description Unused Port

I need to search each port on the cisco switch for this description.  I am having an issue with verifying each port.

Answer (score 1):

As others noted, "|" in the first is obviously errant, since there would be no need to repeat it, and thus should be [123456789] or [1-9]. Beyond that, it is also worth noting that in a numeric context there would be no functional difference with this exact data, hiding a logical bug, because they both happen to contain only single characters (the second "strings" just happen to be single characters). However, ([1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10]) and (1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10) would not be functionally the same even in the numeric context, since only the first would match "0" (with redundant "1" as well as extraneous "|") and only the second would match 10. Noting this might further help clarify confusion, and potential bugs that make this important.

Comment: This is not correct. Bracket notation means that which is enclosed in brackets is a set of "chooseable" elements, and; therefore, `|` can be chosen, which is not desirable.

Comment: Thank you, I stand properly corrected, and updated my comment in hopes it remains of some use (hope that is appropriate).